# Android video stream from url over the videoview or surfaceview

Tags: android, video-streaming, surfaceview, android-videoview

There are so many posts on the same topic but no one is giving proper reason for this error, Could some one help me to solving this error.
My code is working fine for SDCARD videos. whenever I try to access it from url it throws this error.

```
W/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open file on client side; trying server side: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: http://download.itcuties.com/teaser/itcuties-teaser-480.mp4
E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147483648)
```

I tried several formats and several urls for everything i am getting the same error.
Internet permissions given.

Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
VideoView video1;
String url ="http://download.itcuties.com/teaser/itcuties-teaser-480.mp4";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    video1 = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video1);
    video1.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(url));
    video1.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
    video1.requestFocus();
    Thread view1=new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_DISPLAY);
            video1.start();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: Do you have your INTERNET permission included in Manifest? Check for that and also include the correct log. The above log is for a different URL.

Comment: Yeah, Internet permissions are given.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to start your view1 thread. Your code loads the video but doesn't play it. Adding this will solve the issue.

```
 view1.start();
```

Comment: No, you haven't started the thread. You are starting the videoview, not the thread.

Comment: If that is the case then it shouldnt work for videos on sd card aslo

Comment: I just tried it on a device and it works for your URL, give it a try and let me know if it works for you or not.

Comment: Which device are you using? I tried by adding the view1.start() at the end of the code, still i am getting the same error.

Comment: Works on my Nexus 5. :)